# NullPointerException ao exibir toda lista em DataTable com PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jboss, primefaces-5.2

Preciso exibir todos os dados da lista no DataTable utilizando PrimeFaces, porém ao alterar o tamanho do rowsPerPageTemplate para 300 os dados até são exibidos na tela, porém as funções de pesquisa (filterBy) e edição de dados param de funcionar.

O seguinte erro é exibido no console:

> 15:11:36,096 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/fgtas].[Faces
>   Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for
>   servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:441)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:71)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:115)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:152)
>   [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:123)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
>   [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
>   [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]

Meu Bean AgenciasMB.java:

```
package managedbean;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import model.Ads;
import model.Agencias;
import model.dao.AgenciasDao;
import model.dao.AdsDao;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import util.JasperImpressao;


@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "agenciasMB")
public class AgenciasMB implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1968663509271177335L;
    /**
         * 
         */

    private String mensagem = "";
    private Agencias agencias = new Agencias();
    private AgenciasDao dao = new AgenciasDao();
    private Date current;

    private List<Agencias> lista = new ArrayList<Agencias>();
    private Agencias nenhum = new Agencias();

    private List<Ads> listaAds = new ArrayList<Ads>();

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        Agencias ag = ((Agencias) event.getObject());       
        //System.out.println(ag.toString());        
        /*
        if (dao.atualizar(ag) == null)
            this.setMensagem("Erro ao atualizar agência");
        else
            this.setMensagem("Dados atualizados com sucesso.");
            */
        if (dao.gravar(ag) == null)
            this.setMensagem("Erro ao atualizar agência");
        else
            this.setMensagem("Dados atualizados com sucesso.");
    }

    public void incluir() {

        if (dao.gravar(agencias) == null)
            this.setMensagem("Erro ao salvar Agencia");
        else
            this.setMensagem("Dados salvos com sucesso.");

    }


    public Agencias getAgencias() {     
        return agencias;
    }

    public void metodo() {
        /*FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        System.out.println("coloquei na sessão: "+agencias.getId());
        session.setAttribute("ID_USUARIO", agencias.getId());*/
        Agencias ag2 = new Agencias();

        System.out.println("blablabla: " + agencias.getId());
    }


    public void setAgencias(Agencias agencias) {
        this.agencias = agencias;
    }

    public AgenciasDao getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(AgenciasDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }


    public List<Ads> getListaAds() {
        if(listaAds.isEmpty()){
            listaAds = new AdsDao().todos();
        }
        return listaAds;
    }

    public void setListaAds(List<Ads> listaAds) {
        this.listaAds = listaAds;
    }

    public String retornaSimOuNao(int simOuNao) {
        //UPDATE agencias SET servidoresConv = 3 WHERE servidoresConv is NULL
        //se for 3, não está cadastrado
        //System.out.println(this.getLista().toString());       
        if (simOuNao == 1){
            return "Sim";
        }           
        if (simOuNao == 0) {
            return "Não";
        }
        else return "";

    }

    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        //Não apagar, apenas não realiza ação nenhuma.
    }

    public String getMensagem() {
        return mensagem;
    }

    public void setMensagem(String mensagem) {
        this.mensagem = mensagem;
    }

    public List<Agencias> getLista() {

        if (lista.isEmpty()) {
            //lista = dao.listar();
            lista = new AgenciasDao().listarOrdenado();
        }

        return lista;
    }

    public void imprimir(){

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
        JasperImpressao jp = new JasperImpressao(); 

        jp.imprimirRelatorioPdf(parameters, "report3.jasper");

    }

    public void imprimirAgencia(){

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
        parameters.put("codigo", agencias.getId());

        JasperImpressao jp = new JasperImpressao();

        jp.imprimirRelatorioPdf(parameters, "agencia.jasper");

    }


    public void setLista(List<Agencias> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }


    public Agencias getNenhum() {
        Long id;
        id = (long) 5;
        nenhum = new AgenciasDao().pesquisarPorId(id);
        return nenhum;
    }

    public void setNenhum(Agencias nenhum) {
        this.nenhum = nenhum;
    }

    public Date getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(Date current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public void importar(String msg) {  
        System.out.println("imopo");
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.execute("alert(msg)");  
//            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert (\"teste\")");  
        }  


    String action;

    //action listener event
    public void attrListener(ActionEvent event){

    action = (String)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("action");

    }

  //get value from "f:param"    
    public String getIpParam(FacesContext fc){    
        Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();    
        return params.get("enderecoip");    
    }    

    public void outcome(){           
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();    
        //System.out.println("MeuTeste: "+getIdProfessorParam(fc));    

    }    



    public void buttonAction2() {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();    
        String ip = getIpParam(fc);        

        try {
            String[] command = { "cmd", "/k", "start", "ping", "-t", ip };
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    //  System.out.println(ip);
    }

    public void addMensagem(String msg1, String msg2) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msgDM", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg1, msg2));
    }

    public void info() {        
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();    
        String ip = getIpParam(fc);
        String pingCmd = "ping " + ip + " -n 10";

        try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);            

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(),"ISO-8859-1"));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages2", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Ping: ", inputLine));
            }
            in.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);            
        }
    }

    public String buttonAction() {      
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();    
        String ip = getIpParam(fc);    
        String pingResult = "";

        String pingCmd = "ping " + ip + " -n 10";
        System.out.println(pingCmd);
        try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);            

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                pingResult += inputLine;
            }
            in.close();
            return pingResult;




        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return "Erro!!";
        }

    }

}
```

O arquivo listarti.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition template="../../template/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <h:form prependId="false" id="form">

            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
            <p:messages id="messages2" showDetail="true" />

            <p:ajaxStatus>
                <f:facet name="start">
                    <h:graphicImage value="ajax-loading-bar.gif" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:ajaxStatus>

            <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="ti" value="#{agenciasMB.lista}"
                rowStyleClass="#{empty ti.ip ? 'esconder' : null}" editable="true"
                paginator="true" rows="45" style="width:''%" lazy="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,45,300">

                <f:facet name="header">
                   Departamento de Tecnologia da Informação (Procergs: 0800-6469191)
                </f:facet>

                <p:commandButton value="Info" id="info"
                    actionListener="#{agenciasMB.info}" update="messages">
                    <f:param name="enderecoip" value="meuip" />
                </p:commandButton>

                <!--                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{agenciasMB.onEdit}" -->
                <!--                    update=":form:messages"  /> -->
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{agenciasMB.onEdit}"
                    update=":form:messages" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{agenciasMB.onCancel}"
                    update=":form:messages" />

                <p:column filterBy="#{ti.agencia}" headerText="Agência" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:103px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Agência" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ti.agencia}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:95px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="IP" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.ip}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{ti.ip}" label="IP" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:85px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Login" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.login}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{ti.login}" label="Login" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{ti.rede}" headerText="Rede"
                    filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:95px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Rede" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.rede}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ti.rede}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="ADSL" itemValue="ADSL" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="PREFEITURA" itemValue="PREFEITURA" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="PROCERGS" itemValue="PROCERGS" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:80px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Velocidade ADSL" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.velocidadeadsl}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{ti.velocidadeadsl}" label="Velocidade ADSL" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:95px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Rede Procergs / Nº ADSL" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.redeadsl}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{ti.redeadsl}"
                                label="Rede Procergs / Nº ADSL" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:90px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Telefone" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ti.telefone}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:90px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Coordenador" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ti.coordenador}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:110px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Endereço" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ti.endereco}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:90px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Horário" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ti.horario}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="text-align: center;width:95px" sortBy="#{ti.tunel}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Túnel" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.tunel}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{ti.tunel}" label="Túnel" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="text-align: center;width:95px"
                    sortBy="#{ti.usuarioTunel}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Usuário do Túnel" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.usuarioTunel}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{ti.usuarioTunel}" label="Túnel" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="text-align: center;width:95px"
                    sortBy="#{ti.numeroChamado}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nº Chamado" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.numeroChamado}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{ti.numeroChamado}" label="Nº Chamado" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Data Chamado"
                    style="text-align: center;width:90px">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.dataChamado}"
                                rendered="#{not empty ti.numeroChamado}">
                                                            <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputMask value="#{ti.dataChamado}" mask="99/99/9999"
                                label="Data do Chamado">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </p:inputMask>

                                                    <p:calendar id="date" readonlyInput="true" value="#{ti.dataChamado}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mindate="#{agenciasMB.current}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Usuário" style="text-align: center;width:60px">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.usuario}" rendered="#{not empty ti.numeroChamado}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ti.usuario}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="0" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Adriano" itemValue="Adriano" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cléber" itemValue="Cléber" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Flávio" itemValue="Flávio" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Luis" itemValue="Luis" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Roger" itemValue="Roger" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Observaçao" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor id="obs">
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ti.obs}"
                                rendered="#{not empty ti.numeroChamado}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                        <p:inputText value="#{ti.obs}"
                                                            label="Observação"   />
                            <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" value="#{ti.obs}"
                                counter="display" maxlength="255" counterTemplate="{0}"
                                autoResize="true" />
                            <h:outputText id="display" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>

                </p:column>

                                    http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml
                <p:column style="width:60px">
                    <p:commandButton value="Ping" id="ajax" update=":form:messages2"
                        actionListener="#{agenciasMB.info}"
                        styleClass="ui-priority-primary">
                        <f:param name="enderecoip" value="#{ti.ip}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:20px">
                    <p:rowEditor>
                    </p:rowEditor>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </h:form>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Cara você debugou seu código?

Comment: sim, não sei se tem haver com a versão do primefaces, mas o que ocorre é que quando se utiliza mais de 4 colunas as funções param de executar.